# Get title out of page link object in advanced custom fields plugin for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the page link object of the advanced custom fields plugin for Wordpress to provide a link to an internal page on my website. What I want to do is to be able to display the title of the linked page as the link text and the page link as the href.

Is there a way to extract only the title of the page link?

Thanks

EDIT: The page that I'm linking will change dynamically for each post that I've called onto a specific page so hardcoding page ids into the template is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Previous answer was very wrong, sorry!

Instead of using page link I used post object instead. Then you can just do the following:

```
<?php
$post_object = get_field('field');
if($post_object) :
    $post = $post_object;
    // Overwrite $post
    setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php
    // Reset $post so the rest of the page works
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

Comment: Don't you mean `if( $post_object )` ?

Answer (score 3):

I know it is an old thread. But after trying to the suggested solution which failed in my case. I wanted to share my solution in case it would help some one.

I needed to get the title and link to an ACF Page Link field in a custom post type "-single.php" template. But I would keep on getting errors and notice.

```
<?php if (get_field('procedure_links')) : ?>
<?php $procedure_links_items =  get_field( 'procedure_links', false, false); ?>
<?php foreach ( $procedure_links_items as $procedure_links_item ) { ?>
  <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($procedure_links_item); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($procedure_links_item); ?>" class="button"><?php echo get_the_title($procedure_links_item); ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Adding ", false, false" to get_field returns only the post IDs. 
The foreach is obviously to loop and echo all values.
Then, you're only left using WP "get_the_permalink" and "get_the_title" using the id as a parameter.

I hope it helps.